# pandas df to spark df conversion takes long time on Databricks notebook

Tags: pandas, apache-spark, pyspark, databricks, azure-databricks

I have a pandas df which is over 10 million in rows. I'm trying to convert this pandas df to spark df using the below method.

```
spark_session = SparkSession.builder.appName('pandasToSparkDF').getOrCreate()
# Pandas to Spark
spark_df = spark_session.createDataFrame(pandas_df)
```

This process is taking ~9 minutes to convert pandas df to spark df of 10 million rows on Databricks.
Which is too long.

Is there any other way where I can convert it faster?

Thanks. Appreciate the help.

Comment: The best approach might be to avoid Pandas entirely if possible.  Can't tell where you're creating `pandas_df`.  Maybe you can just read from disk right into a PySpark DataFrame.  I think Pandas should always be avoided in PySpark because Spark is a cluster computing framework and Pandas only runs on the driver node.

Answer (score 1):

What driver node size did you use?

One more thing,
Did you do this:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

# Enable Arrow-based columnar data transfers
spark.conf.set("spark.sql.execution.arrow.enabled", "true")

# Generate a pandas DataFrame
pdf = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(100, 3))

# Create a Spark DataFrame from a pandas DataFrame using Arrow
df = spark.createDataFrame(pdf)
```

Check https://docs.databricks.com/spark/latest/spark-sql/spark-pandas.html